# I am looking for a paper by Zalgaller

Tags: reference-request, paper-request

I cannot find this paper online. Does anyone have a pdf file of it?

Zalgaller, V. A.
The k-dimensional directions that are singular for a convex body F in Rn. (Russian)
Zap. Naučn. Sem. Leningrad. Otdel. Mat. Inst. Steklov. (LOMI) 27 (1972), 67–72.

The paper also appears in the collection:

Boundary value problems of mathematical physics and related questions in the theory of functions. 6.
A collection of articles edited by A. V. Ivanov, A. P. Oskolkov and V. A. Solonnikov dedicated to Olga Aleksandrovna Ladyženskaja on her fiftieth birthday. Translated from the Russian. J. Soviet Math. 3 (1975), no. 4. Consultants Bureau, New York, 1975. pp. i–v and 387–584.

Comment: There is an English PDF on [Springer](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01084682), and Google Scholar gives [this](https://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=znsl&paperid=2499&option_lang=eng) for the Russian version. Where did you search?

Comment: @CommandMaster Thank you so much. Apparently, I did not do a good job in search.

Comment: @CommandMaster If you write it as an answer I will vote it up and approve. You were the first to answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an English PDF on [Springer](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01084682), and Google Scholar gives [this](https://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=znsl&paperid=2499&option_lang=eng) for the Russian version.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the URL of this pdf file:

https://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=znsl&paperid=2499&option_lang=rus

Comment: Thank you, but URL for both English and Russian versions have already been provided by Command Master. in his comment.